# What is the best way to pass variables among tests from data entry till validation?

Tags: validation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have some test cases for a web application in `Robot Framework`. In some cases I define a unit and then validate this action by checking database and GUI. The variables which I use in define, should be available in validation in order to check details; keep in mind they are randomly generated in the test case. I have three approaches in mind to pass variables from define to validation:

1. Make variables global and use their global names further; it makes the scenarios ambiguous since the reader can't detect where did this variable come from without checking inner steps.
2. Pass variables to both define and validation keywords; scenarios look weird when vast number of parameters are required.
3. Save variables in a dictionary and pass it to both define and validation keywords.

Which one is the best? Are there any other ways to do the process? Are there any other pros and cons which I've forgotten?

Comment: I would say #3 :) Seems the most logical and "Cleanest" way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally use a combination of #2 & #3. I used #3 in the top level of test cases and #2 for some inner keywords which don't need all the data and a subclass of that is sufficient for them.

Answer (score 2):

3rd option is better to storing variables in dictionary.
There is similar way out also

Consider following is keyword

```
My Keyword
[Argument]    @{data}
// get respective values from keys and use further for validation
${value1}=   Get Template Value From List    ${Key1}    @{data}
${value2}=   Get Template Value From List    ${Key2}    @{data}
```

Call above keyword as follows

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test data
My Keyword
...   key1=value1
...   key2=value2
```

1. So above code will increase **readability** as you know what kind of data your test case is using
2. As you are passing data at your test case level, you don't need to go anywhere else to find data.